# Adding an Interior Door on a Stair Landing

Tags: doors, stairs, sound-proofing, interior, door-frame

*Update 1/26/2017
Ok, it looks like a traditional door may not work...

What about an accordion style door? There are likely studs at both the corner and at the opposite wall on the landing that would accomodate a frame for an accordion style door. I'm thinking there would be a piece at the top to house the rollers, a piece on one side to hold the door, and a magnetic latch on the other side to keep the door closed.
(We would rather not have to install it at the bottom of the stairs, for aesthetic purposes.)

---

In my father's house, there is an upstairs bonus room, which I will be using as a bedroom temporarily. We are trying to figure out a way to add an interior door at the first stair up from the landing in order to block out light and noise for sleeping purposes. The ceiling in the picture extends above that first step, so the door will be the height from that step to the ceiling. That height is 86.25", and the width from wall to wall is 36".

Any ideas on how to do this? What kind of door/frame to use? Some sort of folding door...?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

View looking up the stairs - the door is to be on that first step to the right of the landing.
[image: View going up the stairs - door to be on that first step to the right of the landing]

View looking down the stairs
[image: View looking down the stairs]

Comment: You might want to check code, I think I remember there needs to be + 3' to a door swing if on a landing or something like that.

Comment: Why can't you put the door at the bottom of the stairs?

Answer (score 2):

> There shall be a floor or landing on each side of a door. Such floor or landing shall be at the same elevation on each side of the door. Landings shall be level except for exterior landings, which are permitted to have a slope not to exceed 1 unit vertical in 50 units’ horizontal (2-percent slope). - Florida Building Code 1008.1.4 2007 - See more at: http://inspectapedia.com/Stairs/Stair_Landings.php#DoorSwing

There's all sorts of code requirements that will not allow a door to be put in there. If you must have a door and not a curtain and you don't care about code, then I would put the door like this:

[image]

You'll have to install a door jamb, I would be surprised if you found a door from a big box store that perfectly fit so you might have to custom build it all yourself. It would be a big project!

Comment: Could a pocket door be retro-fitted into the rail side of the wall? Having a door swinging on a landing is not fun. Our out side door swings in to the landing that leads down to the basement. Just enough room to stand on the landing and open the door, but one day, I'm going to lose my balance.

Comment: @Jim a pocket door would be a great option if it's not a load bearing wall, and you'll have to tear into the wall to remove studs that would be in the way. If it is a load bearing wall then you'll have to install a header and idk if one could reasonable fit and I don't think it would be worth all the effort

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a heavy curtain rather then a door?  Cheaper, less work, less permanent.  Will certainly handle the light, and help a bit with noise.